Archive React Native to *.xcframework to using at other iOS project
I want to archive library React Native to *xcframework (as React-Core.xcframework).
I try run command at folder ios:
    xcodebuild archive \
  -workspace ReactNativeProject.xcworkspace \
  -scheme React-Core \
  -destination "generic/platform=iOS Simulator" \
  -archivePath "./build/ios_simulators/React-Core.xcarchive" \
  SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
  BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \
  -verbose

and it made file React-Core.xcarchive, but in that hasn't folder Products/Library. It only has folder usr. So, I don't convert it to .xcframework.
Please advise me how to fix this error, thanks
